# Make e-showcase using Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, e-commerce, drupal-modules

I'd like to make a e-showcase (eshop, but you can't buy things) using Drupal 7. I've managed to make a custom content type for goods with custom fields, including multiple images (Image field, multiple).

I have two questions:

1 - How to program custom look for my custom content type?

2 - How to make image gallery (like nextgen gallery in WordPress) for the specific good, based on the information (images) from the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a custom look for your content type pages, you need to create a new node template and place it into your theme directory.
If your content type machine name is **goods**, then the node template have to be named **node--goods.tpl.php** (For Drupal 7).

To make things easier, just copy the node.tpl.php from your drupal inistallation "modules/node/node.tpl.php" to your theme folder, rename it to node--goods.tpl.php and make all the changes you need.

P.S. Don't forget to clear the cache.

Hope this helps,

Muhammad

Comment: Muhammad, thanks a lot. That's kind of what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. Really glad that helped.
If you're interested in learning more about Drupal 7 template suggestions, the following link'd be your best resource http://drupal.org/node/1089656

Muhammad.

Answer (score 1):

For theming by content type, see the [Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) page.

There are plenty of ways to create image galleries in Drupal, just do a little searching on Google.  Use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow), or [Lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) or [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox), etc